# AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python, python-3.x, posix, spectrogram

i am using the spectrographic library [spectrographic library](https://github.com/LeviBorodenko/spectrographic)

to generate audio file from an image,

from the library documentation i execute this code:

`python spectrographic.py --image ./source.png --min_freq 10000 --max_freq 20000 --duration 10 --save sound.wav --play`

and i am able to hear the generated output audio file successfully, but after the audio finishes, i get this error in terminal:

**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spectrographic.py", line 457, in <module>
    run()
  File "spectrographic.py", line 453, in run
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "spectrographic.py", line 447, in main
    sg.save(wav_file=args.save_file)
  File "spectrographic.py", line 173, in save
    wavio.write(wav_file, self.sound_array, self.SAMPLE_RATE)
  File "/home/mohamed/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wavio.py", line 390, in write
    w.writeframes(wavdata)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/wave.py", line 438, in writeframes
    self.writeframesraw(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/wave.py", line 427, in writeframesraw
    self._ensure_header_written(len(data))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/wave.py", line 468, in _ensure_header_written
    self._write_header(datasize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/wave.py", line 472, in _write_header
    self._file.write(b'RIFF')
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'write'
Exception ignored in: <function Wave_write.__del__ at 0x7fd831e82820>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/wave.py", line 327, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/wave.py", line 445, in close
    self._ensure_header_written(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/wave.py", line 468, in _ensure_header_written
    self._write_header(datasize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/wave.py", line 472, in _write_header
    self._file.write(b'RIFF')
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'write'
```

**

i am using python 3.8.10 on linux ubuntu.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should probably file a bug with them on their github page.

Comment: ^yep, what he said

Comment: i filed a bug in their repo's page, and i hoop they fix it soon, i really liked the easiness of using this library to output audio from images, isn't there any way we can get rid of the error above and save the output file successfully....i can hear the output playback....but no saving :(